# Network Simulation for MANET Addressing scheme

Tags: routes, ns2, ns-3, addressing

I have designed a new addressing scheme for MANET but I am not able to simulate my algorithm. Are there any network simulators that I should consider that would help me with the simulation? Can addressing schemes be simulated using ns3? I would like to make it clear that I am interested in analyzing addressing parameters rather than routing parameters.

Comment: You can do a lot of things with the ns-3 simulator. The only problem is that this simulator required high knowledge of C++ programming. You'll need to modify some ns-3 modules already existing in order to implement and simulate what you want. This will not be simple.